# Java Multi-Level Comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, comparator

I am working on a problem where I must take these "Song-artist pairs" from an input file and sort alphabetically. The guidelines to the sorting goes like so:

- Should sort the song-artist pairs by the name of the author first.
- Once sorted by the artists, if there are multiple songs by the same artist, they should be sort alphabetically as well.
- If the artists name starts with "The", ignore it for sorting purposes.

My problem is that when I am sorting these, I am able to get the artists sorted properly, but then I cannot sort the songs under the conditions that they have the same artist.

This is what the input file would look like:

```
    Hello - Adele
    Yesterday - The Beatles
    Love Me Like You Do - Ellie Goulding
    Hey Jude - The Beatles
    Istanbul - They Might Be Giants
```

I have properly read through the input file, but so far my comparator only sorts the artists alphabetically.  This is what my comparator looks like:

```
    public static class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song>{
        public int compare(Song a, Song b){
            return a.effectiveAuthor().compareTo(b.effectiveAuthor());
        }
    }
```

(I have created a class to easily keep track of the songs and their artists. The effectiveAuthor() method returns the string of the author without the "The " in front of the name)

When calling Arrays.sort() with the array of Song objects and comparator, this is the output I get:

```
    Hello - Adele
    Yesterday - The Beatles
    Hey Jude - The Beatles
    Love Me Like You Do - Ellie Goulding
    Istanbul - They Might Be Giants
```

This is what the output with the proper sorting would look like:

```
    Hello - Adele
    Hey Jude - The Beatles
    Yesterday - The Beatles
    Love Me Like You Do - Ellie Goulding
    Istanbul - They Might Be Giants
```

My original idea was to loop through the array and find the songs with the same artist, and find a way to sort them and re-insert those back into that array, which is a bit complex. I was told that I could use a more comprehensive comparator by having them sort both the artist and song names, and that I would only need to call Arrays.sort once for all of the Song objects.

Can somebody show me how to make a more comprehensive comparator that would pertain to this situation? I currently only know two ways that I can use a comparator, which is to compare numerical values(aka if a > b return -1, if a == b, return 0, and if a < b, return 1), and String values(aka a.compareTo(b)), but I do not know how I would be able to make a more elaborate comparator to help me out with being able to sort by artist first and then the song name.

Thank you

PS: [This](https://pastebin.com/9fFP8g2t) is a pastebin to the java program I mentioned, if you would like more insight on the problem I am trying to solve. [This](https://pastebin.com/Ny6Rbqvm) is what the text file would look like that I am parsing through, where the first line is the number of test cases, followed by a number with the amount of song-artist pairs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say the class you said you managed to create is called `SongArtistPair` and it has a method called `effectiveAuthor()`which returns the author's name without the `The`, and a method `getSongName()` which returns the name of the song. You can use this pattern offered by the Java 8 `Comparator` API.

```
Comparator<SongArtistPair> comp = Comparator.comparing(SongArtistPair::effectiveAuthor).thenComparing(SongArtistPair::getSongName);
```

After that, just use that `comp` as normal

Check Comparator API docs for more cool stuff [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: While this solution does properly work, may you please explain how the comparator `comp` actually compares the authors first and then the song titles. This is my first year of Java so I am not completely familiar with sorting and comparators.

Comment: So `Comparator.comparing` is a static method which takes a functional interface called `Function` which allows you to extract the **key** with which to compare the elements in your array, and returns a `Comparator` instance, then use another `Function` to specify a second **key** to compare by when two objects are considered equal by the first **key**. Not sure if that makes sense, the Javadocs should explain it better than I do though

Comment: @Wup123 Beside the answer you might have a look at this post [which explains the Lambda solution in comparison to the non-Lambda solution](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-sort-lambda).

Comment: @Dummy I do understand how the `Function` interface works, but may you please elaborate a bit more on how the **key** is created?

Answer (score 2):

In your compare method, compare the song titles if the artists names are identical. Like this:

```
public static class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song>{
    public int compare(Song a, Song b){
        int rslt a.effectiveAuthor().compareTo(b.effectiveAuthor());
        if (rslt ==0)
        {
            // compare song names
            rslt = a.getSongName().compareTo(b.getSongName());
        }
        return rslt;
    }
}
```